# How to determine plugin id for 3rd party gradle plugin library?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

For integration test requirement I want to use gradle plugin 'gradle-processes':
https://github.com/johnrengelman/gradle-processes

So I have added version(0.3.0 is only version I see without our organization) in classpath dependency :

`dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:gradle-processes:0.3.0'
    }`

along with 
`apply plugin: 'com.github.jengelman.gradle-processes'`

But gradle run fails stating that: 
Plugin with id 'com.github.jengelman.gradle-processes' not found.

In my local machine repo I can see the jar get downloaded properly, only issue is I am unable to understand what plugin Id I should apply.

Even I went through 
https://github.com/johnrengelman/gradle-processes but couldn't get the answer.

Any help to understand how plugin id get determined for a plugin will be really helpful.
Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Understood the plugin Id concept, so may be useful reference for someone else
https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-plugins/#declare_a_plugin_identifier

Comment: This is a good lead to find the answer to your question, but seems like this link - at least for me - fails to load. Please verify it.